# Using android account credentials to send emails

Tags: java, android, email

I'm looking into building an email client for Android, and I noticed that the default Email app on android can use an account on the device to get email credentials. For an exchange email account I was able to get it connected with the Android account system, but not with K-9 mail. The default app now works fine as a client, but is really clunky.
I've been looking though the source code of AndroidMail and MailActivity, but I haven't had much luck finding anything relevant to that.
My goal is to let users connect their email accounts using the Android accounts system, and then use that account in the email client. Is this possible?

Comment: AccountManager is what's it's called. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html So you were successful in connecting AccountManager with Exchange? but not K-9 mail? Is that correct? What errors are you getting with K-9?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to pass in your email bits (To, Subject, Message) as an intent to Android and let the user pick the best installed app to handle it.  Here is a method I use in one of my apps.  for the "To" parameter you need to pass a string array as to handle multiple recipients.

```
 private void sendMailAsIntent(String mTo, String mSubject, String mMessage) {

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        String aEmailList[] = { mTo };
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mSubject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mMessage);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send E-mail..."));
}
```